# Attribute name change for inherited classes. Possible/Bad practice?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Q1.** If I have a very general class, with an attribute whose name could be better represented in more specific inherited classes, how can I access the same methods from the parent class if the attribute has changed its name? For example (not my real scenario, but it shows what I mean).

```python
class Entity(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.members= {}

  ... # Methods that use self.members


class School(Entity):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Entity,self).__init__(self)

class Company(Entity):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Entity,self).__init__(self)
```

for `class School` and for `class Company`, I would like to be able to use attributes that are more specific, such as `self.students` and `self.employees`, but that still work with the methods that were defined for `self.members` in the `class Entity`.

**Q2.** Would this be bad practice? What would be the best way to approach this? In my real case, the word I used for `self.members` is too general.

Comment: Data duplication is typically a bad practice yes, but you could for example define a `@property` to alias these.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean adding a `@property` in the subclasses to access `self.members` through `self.employees` and `self.students`?

Comment: No, you keep it all as `.members`, and alias it to `students` with `@property`. But typically adding specific names is in my opinion not a good idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming an attribute in a subclass is bad practice in general.

The reason is that [inheritance is about substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). What it means for a `School` to be an `Entity` is that you can use a `School` in any code that was written to expect an `Entity` and it will work properly.

For example, typical code using an `Entity` might do something like this:

```
for member in entity.members:
```

If you have something that claims to be an `Entity` (and even passes `isinstance(myschool, Entity)`), but it either doesn't have `members`, or has an empty `members`, because its actual members are stored in some other attribute, then that code is broken.

More generally, if you change the interface (the set of public methods and attributes) between a base class and dericed class, the derived class isn't a subtype, which means it usually shouldn't be using inheritance in the first case.<sup>1</sup>

---

If you make `students` into an *alias* for `members`, so the same attribute can be accessed under *either* name, then you *do* have a subtype: a `School` has its `students` as `members`, and therefore it can be sensibly used with code that expects an `Entity`:

```
myschool.students.append(Person(cap'))
# ...
for member in myschool.members:
    # now cap is going to show up here
```

And this works just as well with methods defined in `Entity`:

```
def slap_everyone(self):
    for member in self.members:
        # this will include cap
        member.slap()

myschool.slap_everyone()
```

---

And you can do this by using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

```
class Student(Entity):
    # ...
    @property
    def students(self):
        return members
    @students.setter
    def students(self, val):
        self.members = val
    @students.deleter
    def students(self):
        del self.members
```

So, this isn't flat-out invalid or anything.

But it is potentially misleading.

Will it be obvious to readers of your code that adding `cap` to `myschool.students` is going to add him to `myschool.members`? If so, it's probably OK. If not, or if you're not sure, then you probably shouldn't do this.

---

Another thing to consider is that a `School` might have multiple kinds of members: students, teachers, administrators, dropouts who hang around their old campus because they don't know where else to find drug dealers, … If that's part of your design, then what you really want is for *members* to be a property, and probably a read-only property at that,<sup>2</sup> and each subclass can define what counts as "members" in a way that makes sense for that subclass.

```
class Entity(object):
    @property
    def members(self):
        return []
    def rollcall(self):
        return ', '.join(self.members)

class School(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super(School, self).__init__()
        self.students, self.teachers = [], []
    @property
    def members(self):
        return self.students + self.teachers

school = School()
school.teachers.append('cap')
school.students.extend(['marvel', 'america, planet'])
print(school.rollcall())
```

This will print out:

```
cap, marvel, america, planet
```

That `school` is working as a `School`, and as an `Entity`, and everything is good.

---

<sub>1. I say *usually* because (regardless of what OO dogma says) there are other reasons for subclassing besides subtyping. But it's still the *main* reason. And in this case, there doesn't appear to be any other reason for subclassing—you're not trying to share storage details, or provide overriding hooks, or anything like that.</sub>

<sub>2. In fact, you *might* even want to drag in the `abc` module and make it an abstract property… but I won't show that here.</sub>

Comment: @abamert in this last case where members is a property, should I define the methods for `class Entity` using `self.members`? Assuming that I have different types of `members` and I return `self.members` as `self.students+self.teachers` for `class School`